# Capturar dato de una tabla html con javascript y guardarlo en una variable. asp.net con visual basic

Tags: vb.net, asp

Tengo un problema con un código que está en .asp con visual basic que no sé bien como explicar, voy a tratar de hacer lo mejor.

Necesito poder capturar un dato de una tabla y enviarlo a una variable.

Este código es antiguo y me pidieron modificarlo, consiste en una aplicación para un supermercado que a medida que le pasas un código de un producto te lo muestra en una tabla en un página html.

Voy a poner el código de las funciones que creo son las más importantes para explicar bien lo que necesito junto con el html.

La tabla

```
<table id="DetalleTable" class="auto-style34" style="background-position: center; border: thin dashed #000000; font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; line-height: inherit; background-image: url('panel control/img/fondo2.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed;">
<tr id="fila1" style="background-color: #3366CC; color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: bold;">
    <td>N°</td>
    <td>Codigo</td>
    <td>Nombre</td>
    <td>UM</td>
    <td>Cantidad</td>
    <td>Descuento</td>
    <td>Precio</td>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>Cod_Doc</td>
    <td>Num_CorrelativoInterno</td>
    <td>Numero_Item</td>
    <td>Cod_Barra</td>
    <td>Mnt_CifUnitario</td>
    <td>Mnt_CifTotal</td>
</tr>
<asp:Label ID="DetalleLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</table>
```

¿Cómo le envío estos datos? Mediante la función **TomarStock**, tiene muchas cosas pero la parte importante es:

```
Me.DetalleLabel.Text = Me.DetalleLabel.Text &
    Fila(Numero, dArticulo.Datos.Codigo, dArticulo.Datos.Descripcion, dArticulo.Datos.Sig_Med, CantidadItem, Descuento, Precio, Total,
    Ingreso.Cod_Doc, Ingreso.Num_CorrelativoInterno, Ingreso.Numero_Item, dArticulo.Datos.CodBarra, Ingreso.Mnt_ValorCif.Value, Mnt_CifTotal) & vbCrLf
```

y la función de **Fila** que me arma la linea con sus etiquetas:

```
Private Function Fila(Numero As Integer, Codigo As Integer, Nombre As String, UM As String, Cantidad As Decimal, Descuento As Integer, Precio As Decimal, Total As Decimal, Cod_Doc As Integer, Num_CorrelativoInterno As Integer, Numero_Item As Integer, Cod_Barra As String, Mnt_CifUnitario As Decimal, Mnt_CifTotal As Decimal) As String
    Fila = "<tr class=""filafondo"" >"
    Fila = Fila & td(Numero.ToString, 0)
    Fila = Fila & td(Codigo.ToString, 0)
    Fila = Fila & td(Nombre, 0)
    Fila = Fila & td(UM, 0)
    Fila = Fila & td(Cantidad.ToString("N3"), 1) 'smiranda - se elimina el formateo N3
    Fila = Fila & td(Descuento, 3)
    Fila = Fila & td(Precio.ToString("N2"), 1) 'smiranda - se elimina el formateo N2 para los decimales
    Fila = Fila & td(Total.ToString("N2"), 1) ' smiranda - se elimia el formateo N2 para los decimales

    Fila = Fila & td(Cod_Doc, 0)
    Fila = Fila & td(Num_CorrelativoInterno, 0)
    Fila = Fila & td(Numero_Item, 0)

    Fila = Fila & td(Cod_Barra, 0)
    Fila = Fila & td(Mnt_CifUnitario, 0)
    Fila = Fila & td(Mnt_CifTotal, 0)

    Fila = Fila & "</tr>"

    Return Fila
    'Return "<tr class=""filafondo"" ><td>" & Nombre & "</td><td>" & Codigo & "</td><td>" & Precio.ToString("N2") & "</td></tr>"

End Function

Private Function td(Numero As Integer, align As Integer) As String
    Return td(Numero.ToString, align)
End Function

Private Function td(Numero As Decimal, align As Integer) As String
    Return td(Numero.ToString, align)
End Function

Private Function td(Cadena As String, align As Integer) As String
    Select Case align
        Case 0
            Return "<td>" & Cadena & "</td>"
        Case 1
            Return "<td align=""right"">" & Cadena & "</td>"
        Case 2 'no es necesario
            Return "<td align=""left"">" & Cadena & "</td>"
        Case 3
            Return "<td align=""center"">" & Cadena & "</td>"
        Case Else
            Throw New NotImplementedException("No tiene para este numero")
    End Select
End Function
```

A medida que yo le paso un código de un producto a la aplicación me va llenando una variable con todos los tr y su contenido y su cierre, en **Me.DetalleLabel.Text**, pongo de ejemplo dos productos:

```
<tr class="filafondo"><td>1</td><td>10741</td><td>CEBOLLA EN ESCAMAS 25 GR- PRMESANA</td><td>UN </td><td align="right">1,000</td><td align="center">0</td><td align="right">390,00</td><td align="right">390,00</td><td>4</td><td>366</td><td>14</td><td>7796373113500</td><td>0,3893</td><td>0,3893</td></tr>
<tr class="filafondo"><td>2</td><td>10746</td><td>CONDIMENTO PARA CARNES 20 GR-PARMESANA</td><td>UN </td><td align="right">1,000</td><td align="center">0</td><td align="right">390,00</td><td align="right">390,00</td><td>4</td><td>366</td><td>12</td><td>7796373114002</td><td>0,3024</td><td>0,3024</td></tr>
```

Teniendo esto, con javascript, tengo una función que cuando le doy click a una fila me captura el valor del primer td, puede ser 1 o 2 para el caso:

```
$('tr.filafondo').click(function () {
    if ($('#EstadoFormularioHidden').val() == 'n' || $('#EstadoFormularioHidden').val() == 'e') {
        console.log('click en el detalle');
        NItem = $(this).context.children[0].innerHTML;
    }
});
```

Y dependiendo de ese valor tengo una función que se llama EditarItem

```
function EditarItem() {
    var table = new NinjaTable('DetalleTable');
    var row = table.Rows(NItem);
    NItem = 0;

    $('#NumeroItemHiddenField').val(row.GetValue(0));
    $('#CodigoTextBox').val(row.GetValue(1));
    $('#CantidadTextBox').val(row.GetValue(4));
    $('#DescuentoTextBox').val(row.GetValue(5));
    $('#PrecioTextBox').val(row.GetValue(6));
    $('#TotalTextBox').val(row.GetValue(7));
    $('#ImagenArticulo').attr('src', "fotoarticulo/" + row.GetValue(1) + ".png");
    $('#DescipcionArticuloLabel').text(row.GetValue(2));
    $('#DescuentoLabel').text('');

    ItemEdicion(true);

    $('#DescuentoTextBox').focus();
    $('#DescuentoTextBox').select();
}
```

actualmente ese NinjaTable me anda molestando y me tira errores en la aplicación, necesito encontrar otra forma de que **var = row** funcione, o más que nada, independiente de si tengo 10 items, al seleccionar el nº 5 donde dice:

```
$('#NumeroItemHiddenField').val(row.GetValue(0));
```

que hace referencia a este campo

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="NumeroItemHiddenField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Sea 5, ya que después habiendo asignado ese valor a la variable escondida la puedo trabajar con esta función:

```
Protected Sub EliminarLinkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EliminarLinkButton.Click
Dim Detalle As New Detalle(Me.DetalleLabel.Text)

Dim ItemDetalle = (From p In Detalle
                    Where p.NumeroFila = CInt(Me.NumeroItemHiddenField.Value)
                    Select p).Single


If Me.Tipo = "b" Or Me.Tipo = "f" Then
    Dim Terra As New TerraEntities
    Dim DetIngreso = (From p In Terra.Det_DocumentosIngreso
                        Where p.Num_CorrelativoInterno = ItemDetalle.Num_CorrelativoInterno And
                            p.Cod_Doc = ItemDetalle.Cod_Doc And p.Numero_Item = ItemDetalle.Numero_Item And p.Cod_Bodega = Me.Cod_Bodega
                        Select p).Single

    DetIngreso.Num_Cantidad_Linea = DetIngreso.Num_Cantidad_Linea - ItemDetalle.Cantidad
    Terra.SaveChanges()
End If


Detalle.Remove(ItemDetalle)

Me.DetalleLabel.Text = ""

For Each det In Detalle

    Me.DetalleLabel.Text = Me.DetalleLabel.Text & Fila(det.NumeroFila, CInt(det.Codigo), det.Nombre, det.UM, CDec(det.Cantidad), det.Descuento, det.Precio, det.Total, det.Cod_Doc, det.Num_CorrelativoInterno, det.Numero_Item, CStr(det.Cod_Barra), det.Mnt_CifUnitario, det.Mnt_CifTotal) & vbCrLf

Next

Me.TotalLabel.Text = Detalle.Sum(Function(p) p.Total).ToString("N2")
End Sub
```

Así elimino la fila del item que seleccione.

PD: Agrego el codigo de **[Ninjatable](https://codeshare.io/2K9Oro)** que se usa en el EditarItem()

Comment: hola, algún admin que me pueda ayudar, quiero cerrar la pregunta ya que ya resolví mi problema, pero para cerrarla me pide votos y eliminarla no me deja por la recompensa. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Este codigo puede ayudarte.
$("#campoallenar").val($("#idtable ."+$(this).attr('class')+" td:nth-child(2)").text());

$(this).attr('class') o $(this).attr('id'), seria el tr clickeado y 
td:nth-child(2), seria la numeracion de los td pertenecientes a ese tr.